# Accessing specific attributes of an array of a user defined type

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object

I'm a beginner in C++ and I am trying to create a program which simulates a flight management system. I have created classes to simplify the process. Right now, I have a class named "Flight" which has other user-defined data types as its attributes. For example, it includes two "Date" objects, for arrival and departure dates of my flight object. I also have an array of 30 "Passenger" objects which represent the passengers on my flight. I'm experiencing difficulty making changes to this array though. I need to write a member function for my Flight class which can delete Passengers from the array given the ID (which is an attribute of Passenger).

I want to try to implement this function by passing it an integer "removeID". This value is then compared to the ID's of the passengers in the array. If it matches, the entry is "deleted" essentially freeing  the space in the array.

My class Flight is defined as such in its own header file.

```
#include <string>
#include "Date.h"
#include "Time.h"
#include "Passenger.h"
#ifndef FLIGHT_H_
#define FLIGHT_H_

class Flight
{
public:
    Flight(std::string, Date, Date, Time, Time);
    float flightTime();
    void addPassenger(Passenger);
    void removePassenger(int);
    bool listChecker(Passenger);
    void flightListPrinter()const;
    int seatsRemaining();

private:
    std::string flightNumber;
    Date arrivalDate;
    Date departureDate;
    Time arrivalTime;
    Time departureTime;
    std::string destination;
    Passenger* passengerList[30];
    int numPassengers;
};
#endif
```

This is the layout of my class Passenger:

```
#include <string>
#include "Date.h"

class Passenger
{
public:
    //Part a)
    // Constructor
    Passenger(int = 1337, std::string = "Name", std::string = "Banana Island", std::string = "(514)514-5145", Date birth=(1,1,1999));
    // Part b)
    int getID();
    std::string getName();
    std::string getAddress();
    std::string getTel();
    Date getBday();
    // Part c)
    void setAddress(std::string);
    void setTel(std::string);
    void setBirthD(Date);
    // Part d)
    void printInfo()const;

private:
    int ID;
    std::string name;
    std::string address;
    std::string Tel;
    Date birthD;
};
```

I'm trying to access the ID, an attribute of the Passenger object, which itself is and attribute of the Flight object. The passengers are all stored in an array called passengerList, it is 30 passengers long. In my main.cpp file, I've defined the remove passenger function as follows:

```
void Flight::removePassenger(int removeThisID) // Passing the ID to remove 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) // Check all the passengers in the array
    {
// Unsure about the way to access the ID. PassengerList[i].ID == removeThisID ?
    }
}
```

Comment: Haven't really started reading yet, but... At the top of the `Flight` header, there are a bunch of `#include`s outside of the include guard (the `#ifndef FLIGHT_H_ #define FLIGHT_H_` code). This won't hurt if the headers are built correctly, but if you have a couple headers like this you can accidentally cause an infinite loop of inclusions or worse. Move the `#include`s inside the include guard.

Comment: While Rick is right, you can't remove from an array, you can move everything in the array back one slot to cover up the removed item. This is what `vector` is quietly doing in the background for you when you remove an item from it. Use the `vector`if you are allowed to. It'll make your job easier in this and many, many other ways.

Answer (score 1):

You can not remove from an array. Its fixed size.
One way would be to recreate the array everytime you change the size,
but that would be quite annoying.

Gladly there is the c++ standard library which you can use to solve 
such problems.

It has a diverse set of [containers](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/) that manage the storage space for their elements and provide member functions to access them.

Replace `Passenger* passengerList[30]` with `std::vector<Passenger> passengerList`

```
void Flight::removePassenger(int removeThisID) // Passing the ID to remove 
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < passengerList.size(); i++)
    {
        // if (passengerList.at(i).getID() == removeThisID)
        if (passengerList[i].getID() == removeThisID)
        {
            passengerList.erase(passengerList.begin()+i);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to replace passengerList.erase(i) with passengerList.erase(passengerList.begin()+i); but this method works very well for me. Thanks a lot for the help, I appreciate it :)

Comment: Side notes: The extra range checking `at` performs that `[]` does not is unnecessary here. Bounding the list with `passengerList.size()` ensures `i` cannot get out of range. Unless you have a multi-threaded system and everything gets a LOT more complicated. Also look into [`std::remove_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) It might be a little less efficient in this case because it always scan the whole list, but turns the function into a one-liner.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't delete from an array, from what I understand of your project I can suggest you 2 things to overcome this problem 
1 - You can store the array in some other data structure in every deletion, and reinitialize it without your target, which is a lot of work OR,
2 - You can use vectors from cpp's standart library (std) which will do the first part for you, automatically. You can check the vectors from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/

Comment: I decided to go with vectors in this case. I have a lot of other methods which involve the use of this list so I think it makes my life the easiest. Thanks for the help! :)